# Why do bash calculations return 1 if the result is zero

Tags: bash

I'm doing simple calculations in bash and I noticed that bash calculations using `expr` return *1* if the result of the calculation is zero.

```
user@machine:~$ expr 42 - 40 ; echo $?
2
0

user@machine:~$ expr 42 - 84 ; echo $?
-42
0

user@machine:~$ expr 42 - 42 ; echo $?
0
1
```

Why does bash do this? Isn't a return value of *1* an indication that the program failed? Doesn't this behaviour violate good practice?

I'm doing some calculations inside a script run with `set -e`.
What is the best way to account for the return value of 1?
I could do

```
expr $var1 - $var2 || true
```

but this would also ignore other exit codes than *1*.

Comment: `man expr`: _Exit status is 0 if EXPRESSION is neither null nor 0, 1  if EXPRESSION is  null  or  0,  2 if EXPRESSION is syntactically invalid, and 3 if an error occurred._ Also, don't use `expr` for arithmetics, they say,

Comment: see also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63166/bash-e-exits-when-let-or-expr-evaluates-to-0

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because at least first read the man page.

Comment: @JamesBrown If that were a valid close reason, you could close hundreds of questions. Alas, it's not.

Comment: I know bash *does* return 1 if the result is 0. I want to know *why* and how to best account for it in scripts.

Comment: bash isn't returning anything; `expr` is the one returning the value you are concerned with.

Comment: It's not `bash`, it's `expr.` Best way to account for it? don't use `expr`. Second best way? `[[ $? > 1 ]]` rather than your usual 0-equality check

Comment: This is a good reason *not* to use `set -e`: not all non-zero exit statuses are errors. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just the mapping of integers (as Boolean values, 0=False, 1=True) to shell exit codes (0=Success, >0=Failure). Note that "failure" does not necessarily mean "program experienced an error and/or crashed". Other programs do similar things:

```
* `grep` exits with 0 if a match is made, 1 if no match is made. 
* `test` exits 0 if its condition is true, 1 if its condition is false.
```

In C, you can use the result of an arithmetic expression directly as the condition of an `if` or `while` statement.

In shell, such statements test the exit code of a command, treating success as analogous to true and failure as analogous to false. In this sense, `expr ...` is short for `test ... -ne 0`.

In a typical language, you write something like

```
# Python
n = 10
while n - 3:   # short for n > 3
    ...
```

`expr` performs arithmetic, so it makes sense for the exit status to allow the same.

```
n=10
while expr "$n" - 3; do
    ...
done
```

Note that you can still detect actual errors, as opposed to Boolean falseness, by checking if the exit status of `expr` is greater than 1.

```
n=10
while true; do    # "Infinite" loop
    expr "$n" - 3
    case $? of
       1)  break ;;
       2)  echo "Error with expr" >&2; break ;;
    esac

    ...
done
```